# Bootloop, Stock Recovery, USB debugging off

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot-loop, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I'm using a *Samsung Galaxy S DUOS GT-S7562* running Android ICS.

Before my phone got bootlooped, I used to change the `build.prop` in
`/system/build.prop` to add a navigation bar to it. I added `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0` at the end of the texts, and did a reboot. Now my device is bootlooping.

I only had a stock recovery, and did a factory reset – but still no luck.
It only boots to the Samsung boot animation.

I tried to enter Download Mode to use Odin, but it surprised me that
I can't even go to USB state; so it's impossible for me to do it also.

And lastly, I don't have a backup either. But I found a firmware exactly for my device.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you try flashing the firmware in fastboot mode?

Comment: Try installing the driver first and then connect the phone

Comment: http://androidofficer.blogspot.com/2014/01/download-usb-driver-for-android.html  Download the USB Drivers for your device. And use Samsung Kies to flash your firmware. If that doesn't work flash it through Odin (PC) or Heimdall (Mac)